# How to properly overload functions

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree, overloading

Hi I was just wondering how I would go about properly overloading functions in a Binary Search Tree. Heres the Code I have:

```
int LessThan(E itm1, E itm2) {
  if (itm1 < itm2) {return -1;}
  else if (itm1 > itm2) {return 1;}
  else if (itm1 == itm2) {return 0;}
}

int LessThan(string s1, string s2) { // Incase it is a string, we need to define <= and >= differently
  return this->compare(s1, s2);
}
```

Unfortunately I'm getting the following errors:

```
binarySearchTree.h:33:9: error: ‘int binarySearchTree<E>::LessThan(std::__cxx11::string, std::__cxx11::string) [with E = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; std::__cxx11::string = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’ cannot be overloaded
 int LessThan(string s1, string s2) { // Incase it is a string, we need to define <= and >= differently
     ^
binarySearchTree.h:27:9: error: with ‘int binarySearchTree<E>::LessThan(E, E) [with E = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’
 int LessThan(E itm1, E itm2) {
     ^
```

Comment: Your answer should really contain a proper [mcve]. Being member functions of a class template is an **important detail**!

Answer (score 2):

Overloading isn't the answer to your problem. You are trying to have a specific behavior when your template is instantiated with a `std::string`. The proper technique is *explicit specialization*. Add the following under your template definition, like so:

```
template<>
int binarySearchTree<std::string>::LessThan(std::string s1, std::string s2) {
  return this->compare(s1, s2);
}
```